# Adding a formula with a variable row refernce

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using populating a sheet using rows.count to add data to the next available row. I'm looking for a way to add a formula to each row but I'm struggling on how to make it work since the formula can't use a definitive row location.  My column will always be "G" but the row is going to be sequential as new rows are populated.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work?
I'm using the below "irow" code to find the row to populate.

```
Dim irow As Long
irow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'part data
With Sheet2
    .Range("A" & irow).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Range("B" & irow).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
```

In this case, I'm trying to add column "N" and "O".

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Would help a lot to show the formulas you're adding.  Difficult to guess what might work best otherwise.

Comment: They are primarily going to be date based formulas.  For example "N2+(O2*7)=lead time"

Answer (score 2):

You could use R1C1 notation for the formula.

```vb
.Range("G" & irow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC14+(RC15*7)"
```

Comment: Thanks, works great

Comment: I would avoid using string math for maintenance reasons. Try `.Range("G1").Cells(irow,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC14+(RC15*7)"` instead.  This way you can move around the top of the table from `G1` to anywhere else easily.

Answer (score 0):

This can work if the formulas contain tokens which can be replaced with the actual row number:

eg:  `=A<r>+(B<r>*7)`

```vb
With Sheet2.Cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlUp).offset(1).Entirerow
    .Columns("A").Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Columns("B").Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    '......
    .Columns("F").Formula = Replace("=A<r>+(B<r>*7)","<r>",.Row) 'for example
end with
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't explain very well.  How would dropping in the formulas work on data not coming from textboxes? eg: Columns A:D have data populated from userform text boxes by a command button. Columns E:F are manual entry.  How would you get G to drop in the formula "E+(F*7)" when the command button sends the data to columns A:D and have that formula work for every line?

Comment: Updated my answer - you should get the idea.